# Problem with query execution time in mongo with spring data

Tags: spring, mongodb, kotlin, mongodb-query, spring-data-mongodb

I have a problem with too long response time with find query.
This is quite strange because if I run the query myself (e.g. via the dataGrip / Intellij driver) the response time is about 500-700 ms, and when it is performed by an service that uses spring data mongo, the response time is from 33000 ms to 45000 ms.
Not only the time is different - but verifying the query more specifically using`.explain(“executionStats”)` - the number of `keysExamined` and `docsExamined`.

This is the query:

```js
db.fooCollection.find({
    "$or": [{
      "$and": [{
        "params": {
          "$elemMatch": {
            "name": "manufacturer",
            "val": "FooManufacturer"
          }
        }
      }, {
        "params": {
          "$elemMatch": {
            "name": "articleId",
            "val": "FOO-FOO-ARTICLE-ID-FOO"
          }
        }
      }]
    }, {
      "$and": [{
        "params": {
          "$elemMatch": {
            "name": "brand",
            "val": "FooManufacturer"
          }
        }
      }, {
        "params": {
          "$elemMatch": {
            "name": "articleId",
            "val": "FOO-FOO-ARTICLE-ID-FOO"
          }
        }
      }]
    }]
  }).collation({
    locale: 'en',
    strength: 1,
    alternate: "shifted",
    maxVariable: "punct"
  })
  .explain("executionStats")
```

This is `executionStats` from manual query run:

```json
{
  "executionSuccess": true,
  "nReturned": new NumberInt("1"),
  "executionTimeMillis": new NumberInt("2"),
  "totalKeysExamined": new NumberInt("1"),
  "totalDocsExamined": new NumberInt("1"),
  "executionStages": {
    "stage": "SUBPLAN",
    "nReturned": new NumberInt("1"),
    "executionTimeMillisEstimate": new NumberInt("2"),
    "works": new NumberInt("2"),
    "advanced": new NumberInt("1"),
    "needTime": new NumberInt("0"),
    "needYield": new NumberInt("0"),
    "saveState": new NumberInt("0"),
    "restoreState": new NumberInt("0"),
    "isEOF": new NumberInt("1"),
    "inputStage": {
      "stage": "FETCH",
      "filter": {
        "$or": [{
          "$and": [{
            "params": {
              "$elemMatch": {
                "$and": [{
                  "name": {
                    "$eq": "articleId"
                  }
                }, {
                  "val": {
                    "$eq": "FOO-FOO-ARTICLE-ID-FOO"
                  }
                }]
              }
            }
          }, {
            "params": {
              "$elemMatch": {
                "$and": [{
                  "name": {
                    "$eq": "brand"
                  }
                }, {
                  "val": {
                    "$eq": "FooManufacturer"
                  }
                }]
              }
            }
          }]
        }, {
          "$and": [{
            "params": {
              "$elemMatch": {
                "$and": [{
                  "name": {
                    "$eq": "articleId"
                  }
                }, {
                  "val": {
                    "$eq": "FOO-FOO-ARTICLE-ID-FOO"
                  }
                }]
              }
            }
          }, {
            "params": {
              "$elemMatch": {
                "$and": [{
                  "name": {
                    "$eq": "manufacturer"
                  }
                }, {
                  "val": {
                    "$eq": "FooManufacturer"
                  }
                }]
              }
            }
          }]
        }]
      },
      "nReturned": new NumberInt("1"),
      "executionTimeMillisEstimate": new NumberInt("0"),
      "works": new NumberInt("2"),
      "advanced": new NumberInt("1"),
      "needTime": new NumberInt("0"),
      "needYield": new NumberInt("0"),
      "saveState": new NumberInt("0"),
      "restoreState": new NumberInt("0"),
      "isEOF": new NumberInt("1"),
      "docsExamined": new NumberInt("1"),
      "alreadyHasObj": new NumberInt("0"),
      "inputStage": {
        "stage": "IXSCAN",
        "nReturned": new NumberInt("1"),
        "executionTimeMillisEstimate": new NumberInt("0"),
        "works": new NumberInt("2"),
        "advanced": new NumberInt("1"),
        "needTime": new NumberInt("0"),
        "needYield": new NumberInt("0"),
        "saveState": new NumberInt("0"),
        "restoreState": new NumberInt("0"),
        "isEOF": new NumberInt("1"),
        "keyPattern": {
          "params.name": new NumberInt("1"),
          "params.val": new NumberInt("1")
        },
        "indexName": "params.name_1_params.val_1",
        "collation": {
          "locale": "en",
          "caseLevel": false,
          "caseFirst": "off",
          "strength": new NumberInt("1"),
          "numericOrdering": false,
          "alternate": "shifted",
          "maxVariable": "punct",
          "normalization": false,
          "backwards": false,
          "version": "57.1"
        },
        "isMultiKey": true,
        "multiKeyPaths": {
          "params.name": ["params"],
          "params.val": ["params"]
        },
        "isUnique": false,
        "isSparse": false,
        "isPartial": false,
        "indexVersion": new NumberInt("2"),
        "direction": "forward",
        "indexBounds": {
          "params.name": ["[CollationKey(0xCOLLECTION_KEY), CollationKey(0xCOLLECTION_KEY)]"],
          "params.val": ["[CollationKey(0xCOLLECTION_KEY_2), CollationKey(0xCOLLECTION_KEY_2)]"]
        },
        "keysExamined": new NumberInt("1"),
        "seeks": new NumberInt("1"),
        "dupsTested": new NumberInt("1"),
        "dupsDropped": new NumberInt("0")
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and this is interesting - from service logs (same query, same db, same index used in execution)

```json
 "planSummary": 
   "IXSCAN { params.name: 1, params.val: 1 }, IXSCAN { params.name: 1, params.val: 1 }",
   "keysExamined": 87182,
   "docsExamined": 87182,
   "cursorExhausted": true,
   "numYields": 484,
   "nreturned": 1,
```

Result of the same query is different in each case (service vs manual run). I tried to use an older version of the mongo driver in dataGrip because I thought maybe it was outdated in the service and thats why it take so long to receive an answer - but nope. Still hand-made is precise and fast.

This is the method in code:

```java
private suspend fun findByParams(parameters: Set < Map < ParamName, ParamValue >> ): CloseableIterator < ProductDocument > {
    val collation = Collation.of("en").strength(1).alternate("shifted").maxVariable("punct")
    val query = Query().collation(collation)
    val criterias = parameters.map {
        set - > set.map {
            Criteria.where("parameters").elemMatch(Criteria.where("name").iseEqualTo(it.key.name).and("value").isEqualTo(it.value.value))
        }
    }
    query.addCriteria(Criteria().orOperator(criterias.mapNotNull {
        Criteria().andOperator(it)
    }))
    return withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
        mongoTemplate.stream(query, ProductDocument::class.java)
    }
}
```

Comment: When we run `.find(...)`, the GUI returns top 50 records, but when we run it in our app, it return all records. To equalize the condition, please add to `.find(...).forEach(print)` (force to return all records). If it still takes 500-700ms, then we investigate.

Comment: I cant call explain with this method so I have got no idea how many docs have been examined- but execution time was ~1000 ms. I was sure that since I use the same query as the one called by the service, there will be no micro-optimization in the background. I still have no idea what could be causing the app to take so long.

Comment: No no, forget about `explain` for the moment. Just run `db.fooCollection.find({...}).forEach(print)` in any GUI (MongoDB shell, Robo3T, Compass) and time the execution result. As I told, most all GUI executes the query and returns top 50 records. It "seems" they run the same query, but it's not true.

Comment: 1241 ms - so still 30-40 times faster than in app

Comment: We can continue in the [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252152/problem-with-query-execution-time-in-mongo-with-spring-data)